# SpringBoot run task without needing to wait for response

Tags: spring, spring-boot, task

I am building a SpringBoot project, where a user can register an account. When a user registers, the database needs to set up their account, which takes around 10 minutes.

While this happens, I want the user to be able to browse my site, with a progress bar showing the status of the database setup. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: If you want to initiate requests from the back-end to your front-end, you should try `Websockets`.

Comment: What do you have so far? Have you made some research and maybe got some directions as to what you should look for?

Comment: @UroshT. I think websockets is the solution, though the documentation for the subject seems complicated and confusing. Before this post, i looked at asynchronous methods, which i think is about multi threading.